# Reading array values in a @Include inside a @foreach - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, laravel, include

I'm stuck with this, still getting the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error.

Thats my code:

```
@foreach ($requests as $request)

@include('sublayout.item_info',array('title' => $request['name'],'thumbnail' => 'img/goku_thumb.gif', 'general_status' => null,'link_url' => $request['studentID'], 'link_desc' => 'Aprovar'))

@endforeach
```

Already checked and if I do {{print_r($request}} with the @include commented, I can see the array printed...

Did a test with the following code:

```
@foreach ($requests as $request)
{{$request['name']}}<br>
{{print_r($request)}}
@endforeach
```

I got:

```
Victor
Array ( [name] => Victor [studentID] => 1 [pivot] => Array ( [subject_id] => 18 [user_id] => 1 ) ) 1 
Wilton
Array ( [name] => Wilton [studentID] => 2 [pivot] => Array ( [subject_id] => 18 [user_id] => 4 ) ) 1
```

Also tried to do something like
    $variable = $request['name']
and use it on the include, but it fail, same error.

Would this be a limitation of Blade layout system?

Thank You!

Comment: Where did the error point to?

Comment: thats return multi array and you must be use two foreach to fetch array

Comment: can you run this code `print_r($requests)` and post the output in your question?

Comment: also , can you show how you are getting `$requests`

Comment: @xdazz , thank you for pointing this out for me... I mean, it was pointing for a foreach, but I didn't payed  attention... It is pointing for a foreach INSIDE the include, that uses an array, that I was supplying with a NULL value... changed it by an empty array() and it is working now :) Thank you All!!